# Action method won't redirect via jQuery.post in .net-core-mvc app

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

```
$.post({
    url: '@Url.Action("Create", "MyController")',
    data: { myVar: myVal }
})
```

In the Controller Action method I'm debugging the parameter value being posted via the jQuery method and I know the method is being called and passed the correct data but the RedirectToAction("Index"); statement doesn't load my other view page.

The debug console shows me a successful get request for the url localhost:xxxxx/MyController/Index.  However, the get request isn't reflected in the browser developer network window.

Comment: `$.post` is an asynchronous call, `RedirectToAction` will not work, instead return a url to redirect and use success callback method to do the needful. OR submit the form

Comment: what method will work?  does this mean that i should be using async Task<IActionResult> for the action method?

Comment: I even tried calling the $.get in the .done() function of the .post call.  the browser developer network tab shows a successful get request and yet it doesn't load the Url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that since your post ajax call is expecting a return instead of redirecting to action try something like passing true instead of redirecting and in ajax success function

```
success:function(data)
{
    if(data)
    {
        var url = '@url.action("yourACtion","yourController")';
        window.location.href = url;
     }
}
```